# AngularJS modal iframe get form values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, modal-dialog

I have an AngularJS project where I open a modal window. In the modalwindow I have an iframe wich loads a external URL. The external url has a form.

Is there a way to access the formvalues without using jquery?

---

So I've got a modal called from my controller:

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : 'modal.html',
        controller  : 'ModalController',
        size        : "lg",
        resolve: {
          options: function () {
            return {
              iframeUrl         : “http://www.myexternalurl",
            };
          }
        }            
    });
```

modal.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <iframe ng-src="{{options.iframeUrl}}" id="myIframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" class="modalIframe"  seamless='seamless' style="border:0" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Modal controller

```
.controller('ModalController' , ['$scope', '$modalInstance' , '$sce' , 'options' , '$document'  , function($scope, $modalInstance , $sce , options , $document)
{    

    $scope.options  = null;

    if(options) {
        $scope.options  = options;

        if($scope.options.iframeUrl) { 
            $scope.options.iframeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.options.iframeUrl);

            $modalInstance.rendered.then(function(){
              var myElement = angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#myIframe'));
              console.log(myElement);
              console.log(myElement.find("form"));
            });            
        }
    }
}]);
```

Form on the external url

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type='text' name='test'>
</form>
```

So from the modal controller I need to access the form (loaded in the iframe) and get the values from the input named test

Comment: Please be precise , show up a code which you want us to do

Comment: If your modal is being passed a controller, you should be able to pass $scope to and fro, or interface through a service. Please post your code so we can see more of what you mean